# How can I see the output of an OS X program being run via the Time Profiler in Instruments?

Tags: xcode, instruments, profiler

For some reason, my OS X app crashes when using the time profiler but not otherwise. I'd like to see the stderr and stdout output from the program to try to diagnose what's wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As of Xcode 13 and 14, the process for viewing a command's output in Instruments has changed. You now need to add the "stdout/stderr" Instrument:

[image: adding the stdout/stderr instrument]

You can then click this instrument in the timeline to view the outputs:

[image: selecting the stdout/stderr instrument in the timeline]

Answer (score 4):

Instruments has a console view. By default, that's where program output goes. (In the Choose Target sheet, you can change that.)

In the Detail area (the bottom half of the window, typically), there's a breadcrumb control along the top. You can use that to show the console view.

[image: Instruments Detail area breadcrumb choosing Console]